# Как в javascript regex делаеть поиск справо-налево или о жадности [\s\S]?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Имеем такой текст:

```
<div></div>bla bla</div>MULTI
LINE TEXT<div class="t1"></div>
```

По нему требуется найти все что левее

```
<div class="t1"
```

и до первого

```
</div>
```

, если искать справо-налево.

В данном примере требуется найти

```
MULTI
LINE TEXT
```

Мое регулярное выражение

```
/<\/div>([\s\S]+?)<div class="t1"/
```

дает такой результат:
`bla bla</div>MULTI
  LINE TEXT`

Как составить запрос так, чтобы `([\s\S]+?)` не был таким жадным и не захватывал бы тот кусок текста, который стоит перед ним.

Comment: Вам ещё никто не говорил, что парсить html регулярками не стоит? Я буду первым.

Comment: Подумайте для начала о том, что может встретиться внутри `<!-- комментария -->`.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так?

```js
function cut(str){
  return (test = /(?:<\/div>)?([\s\S]*?)<div\s+class="t1"/.exec(str)) ? /^([\s\S]+?)>vid\s*\/</.exec(test[1].split('').reverse().join(''))[1].split('').reverse().join('') : null;
}

// Никак не смог придумать чтобы регулярка искала справа налево (нужно взять ближайший "</div>" от "<div class='t1'", а она берёт ближайший к началу), пришлось немного... извратиться...
// Если кто-то знает как одной регуляркой это сделать - поделитесь, пожалуйста, я, кажется, туплю :)
console.info(cut('<div></div>bla bla</div>MULTI<>\nLINE TEXT<div class="t1"></div>'));
```

Ограничить жадность квантификатора можно поставив после них вопросительный знак:

```js
var str = '123456';

// Жадный
var greedy = /(\d+)/.exec(str); // Захватит максимум цифр: 123456

// Эмн... не жадный :)
var generous = /(\d+?)/.exec(str); // Захватит как можно меньше цифр: 1

console.info("Greedy: " + greedy[1] + "\nGenerous: " + generous[1]);
```

Comment: Если внутри искомого текста окажется символ >, то поиск будет неверным.
Например ```"<div></div>bla bla</div>MU>LTI\nLINE TEXT<div class="t1"></div>"```

Comment: @p2mbot, Хак сработал, обновил пост.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var text = "<div></div>bla bla</div>MULTI\nLINE TEXT<div class=\"t1\"></div>";
var find = function ( text ) {
    return /<\/div>((?:[^<]+|<(?!\/div>))*)<div class="t1"/.exec( text )[1];
};
console.log( find ( text ) );
document.body.innerHTML = "<PRE>"+ find ( text ) + "</PRE>"; // addaptation to snippet StackExchange
```

Comment: Злободневный вопросик: А если не будет впереди закрывающего `</div>`? Да, абшибка :)
Правда я не понял как работает просмотр назад с отрицанием - у меня он никак не работал...

Comment: @TheDoctor, отсутствие закрывающего DIV не входит в условия вопроса, впрочем если убрать из начала регулярного выражения этот самый DIV, то и в тексте он перестанет требоваться.

Answer (score 0):

```
'<div></div>bla bla</div>MULTI\n\
LINE TEXT<div class="t1"></div>'.match(/<\/div>(((?!<\/div>)[\s\S])+)<div class="t1"/)[1]
```

Comment: @TheDoctor, закрывающаяся скобка в конце лишняя. Почему она появилась при твоём редактировании?

Comment: Странно, я не редактировал этого сообщения...
Откатил к первому ответу.